# An efficient algorithm to sample non-duplicate random elements from an array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm to pick M random elements from a given array. The prerequisites are:

- the sampled elements must be unique,
- the array to sample from may contain duplicates,
- the array to sample from is not necessarily sorted.

This is what I've managed to come up with. Here I'm also making an assumption that the amount of unique elements in the array is greater (or equal) than M.

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


const std::vector<int> sample(const std::vector<int>& input, size_t n) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, input.size() - 1);
    
    std::vector<int> result;
    result.reserve(n);

    size_t id;
    do {
        id = dist(engine);
        if (std::find(result.begin(), result.end(), input[id]) == result.end())
            result.push_back(input[id]);
    } while (result.size() < n);

    return result;
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> input{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4};

    std::vector<int> result = sample(input, 3);

    for (const auto& item : result)
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This algorithm does not seem to be the best. Is there a more efficient (with less time complexity) algorithm to solve this task? It would be good if this algorithm could also assert the amount of unique elements in the input array is not less than M (or pick as many unique elements as possible if this is not the case).

**Possible solution**

As MSalters suggested, I use `std::unordered_set` to remove duplicates and `std::shuffle` to shuffle elements in a vector constructed from the set. Then I resize the vector and return it.

```
const std::vector<int> sample(const std::vector<int>& input, size_t M) {
    std::unordered_set<int> rem_dups(input.begin(), input.end());
    if (rem_dups.size() < M) M = rem_dups.size();
    
    std::vector<int> result(rem_dups.begin(), rem_dups.end());
    std::mt19937 g(std::random_device{}());
    std::shuffle(result.begin(), result.end(), g);

    result.resize(M);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The standard library has [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) that you could use as part of a solution.

Comment: For a *simple* algorithm: Select a random element from the vector. Put it in a `std::unordered_set` (or `std::set` if you want the values ordered). Do in a loop until the set size is the same as the wanted number of elements.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was thinking of that, but I'm not sure if it is more efficient in terms of time complexity

Comment: @Kaiyakha It surely is, your version has quadratic time complexity.

Comment: what about asserting the amount of uniques is not less than M? Otherwise there will be an infinite loop

Comment: (1) Use `std::unique()` to reorder the array, and obtain a smaller range with unique elements (duplicates moved outside that range). (2)  Check that the number of unique elements does not exceed `M`  (no need to assume) (3) Shuffle the unique set (4) Copy the first `M` elements from one end of the shuffled set. In terms of time complexity, `std::unique()` is linear in total number of elements, shuffling and copying elements is linear in number of elements affected.  That will beat your approach which (appears on a superficial look) to be quadratic in number of elements.

Comment: I would expect that your C++ class's instructor or your C++ textbook would explain the underlying algorithm before assigning the practice program to code it. What in that explanation, ***specifically*** that's unclear?

Comment: Do you want an element that shows up more often in the input to be more likely to show up (once) in the output, or do you want all distinct elements to be equally likely in the output?

Comment: @Dave in this case it does not matter to me

Comment: @Peter: `std::unique` requires a sorted input, that's how it can be linear, but the input isn't sorted here. And if you add a ` std::sort`,, your suggestion no longer has linear complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comments already note the use of `std::set`. The additional request to check for M unique elements in the input make that a bit more complicated. Here's an alternative implementation:

1. Put all inputs in a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`. This removes duplicates.
2. Copy all elements to the return vector
3. If that has more than M elements, `std::shuffle` it and `resize` it to M elements.
4. Return it.

Comment: Note that this is reasonably efficient if M is similar to the number of unique elements. If M is relatively small, you spend a lot of time shuffling elements that you're going to discard anyway. In this case, you can use the original approach to repeatedly pick elements, discarding duplicates using a set. But since you're now choosing from a vector that's already de-duplicated, picking duplicates if less likely.

Answer (score 1):

Use a set S to store the output, initially empty.

```
i = 0

while |S| < M  && i <= n-1
  swap the i'th element of the input with a random greater element
  add the newly swapped i'th element to your set if it isn't already there
  i++
```

This will end with S having M distinct elements from your input array (if there are M distinct elements). However, elements which are more common in the input array are more likely to be in S (unless you go through the additional work of eliminating duplicates from the input first).

Comment: Good remark: the question doesn't mention whether non-unique inputs should be more likely to appear in the output. This is non-trivial. Consider the case where M=2 and the input is {1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3}. There are obviously three possible outcomes; what should the likelihoods be? Obviously p({1,3})==p({2,3}) but what should that be?

Comment: @MSalters In the comments to the OP's question, the OP stated that it was fine for more frequent elements in the input array to be more common in the output.

Comment: @Dave yes, in my case it is not important, but that's still a useful remark